# How to check if a url contains video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

hi
i am creating a script ruby on rails in which user shares a link and if the link contains a video, the embed code of the video is extracted. in other words, i am trying to implement a "facebook post link" like feature.. can someone please guide me how can this be achieved??

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do this would be to manually check each post for a link to the video, for example:

```
  YOUTUBE_EMBED = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'    
  if comment =~ /.*http:\/\/(\w+\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?v=(\w+).*/
    return YOUTUBE_EMBED.gsub(/VIDEO_ID/, $2)  
  end
```

Then repeat this process for each video site. I am wrestling with a similar concept so if you figure out a better way to do it let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze http headers for that link

```
require "net/http"

Net::HTTP.start('www.jhepple.com', 80) do |http|
 http.head('/support/SampleMovies/MPEG-1.mpg')
end['content-type']
```

Outputs `"video/mpeg"`

Now that you know it's really a video, do what you want with it

Comment: This will only work if it is a direct link to the video file. @Saad is this what you were referring to, or did you want to detect the the webpage contained a video (which is much harder).

Comment: i basically want to detect if the webpage contains a video and if it does then extract the embed url of the video

Comment: To do this with precision may require more than will fit in a Stackoverflow post.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction? as in what should i explore to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a utility like `file` and fork a system process so that it executes a command like `file -b downloaded_file.mpg`.

So your code would look something like this:

```
IO.popen("file -b /path/to/video.mpg") { |stdout| @stdout = stdout.gets }
if not @stdout.grep(/MPEG/).empty?
   puts "MPEG Detected"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Flash videos usually have the extension .flv, so you just need to look for files that have it.

```
html_souce.scan(%r|href\s*=\s*\"[^\"]+\.flv\"|)
```

If you need other file formats, just change the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external service like [embedl.ly](http://embed.ly)

Here you're a gem that may help you https://github.com/judofyr/ruby-oembed